# Pythons Elasticsearch-DSL filter for exactly one match from list of values

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, querydsl, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I saw some realted posts but none of them match my exact issue.

Using Python 2.7 with Elasticsearch-dsl (6.3, that is also my Elasticsearch version).

I want to do something like,

`s = Search(using=elastic_conn, index='my_index').filter("match", service_name=['exmp_name1', 'exmp_name2'])`

This syntax doesn't work though.

I wish to get back all documents with `service_name == 'exmp_name1'` OR `service_name == 'exmp_name2'`

I prefer to use the filter context rather then query context as from my understanding it's faster and scoring really isn't important to me, just an absolute match (or mismatch).

How can I achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. All I needed is to filter by `terms` rather then `match`.

The `terms` syntax supports several values.

Working code:

`s = Search(using=elastic_conn, index='audit').filter("terms", service_name=['exmp_name1', 'exmp_name2'])`